# How to place Controls in powerbuilder toolbar

Tags: powerbuilder

Hello 
Am looking for simple code which will help me to add controls to the toolbar. Controls like SLE, DDLB. I want to place this control in common. So I want to place those controls in toolbar. Does anybody know about this code kindly notify me. I have found one code on internet. But for me as a student I can't understand that code. Kindly give the solution on simple format.**

### Thanks and Regards

**Raj**

Answer (score 1):

You can either develop a 'toolbar like' control using a datawindow or userobject or utilize a third party control.  Depending upon the version of PB you are using there are examples of advanced graphic techniques included within the sample applications provided with PowerBuilder.  One of these tools is the pre-cursor to Brad Wery's PB Ultimate Suite available from Novalys (www.novalys.net).  You will have to examine the sample code to pick out how to use the control in your own application.  This is the way you learn.